# Getting NullPointerException from Bitmap compress

Tags: java, bitmap, compression

I saw some things around, so that my code is really similar to the one you can easily find around :)
But I can't make it work sadly, getting the following exception:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean
>   android.graphics.Bitmap.compress(android.graphics.Bitmap$CompressFormat,
>   int, java.io.OutputStream)' on a null object reference
>               at monsita.h24shops.MapsActivity.upload(MapsActivity.java:301)

I call the `takePic()` method from a button.
I can take the picture, I see it in my gallery, in the right folder that

```
Log.e("path", "----------------" + picturePath);
```

gives me. 
These are the functions I use:

```
int TAKE_PHOTO_CODE = 0;
public static int count = 0;
public static String ba1;
String picturePath;

public void takePic(){

    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("label", 0);

    count = sharedpreferences.getInt("lastpic", 0);

    //here,we are making a folder named picFolder to store pics taken by the camera using this application
    final String dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) + "/picFolder/";
    File newdir = new File(dir);
    newdir.mkdirs();

    // here,counter will be incremented each time, based on getInt by sharedpref
    count++;
    String filePath = dir+count+".jpg";
    File newfile = new File(filePath);

    try {
        newfile.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {}

    Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(newfile);

    picturePath = filePath;
    Toast.makeText(this,picturePath,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);

    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, TAKE_PHOTO_CODE);
}







@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == TAKE_PHOTO_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        upload();
    }
}




 private void upload() {

    Log.e("path", "----------------" + picturePath);

    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath, options);
    //options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);
    options.inSampleSize = Utils.calculateInSampleSize(options, 150, 150);

    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath,options);  //options added
    ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    //bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bao);     //90,50... is pic quality from 1 to 100
    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 30, bao);

    byte[] ba = bao.toByteArray();
    //ba1 = Base64.encodeBytes(ba);    //era encodeBytes
    ba1 = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(ba));

    Log.e("base64", "-----" + ba1);

    //android:largeHeap="true" added in Manifest to manage big bitmap and avoid OOM error

    // Upload image to server
    new uploadToServer(MapsActivity.this,mapManager.getclickedMarkerID()).execute();
}
```

In the manifest I have:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="monsita.h24shops.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2" android:required="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.camera" />
```

Comment: Well presumably `BitmapFactory.decodeFile` has returned null, which it's documented that it can do...

Comment: The path is correct. So that it's strange it fails always.

Comment: I deleted

    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

and it goes allright.
I will try to understand better the reason.